# ¿Cómo anular el cambio automatico de ancho de las columnas de Bootstap?

Tags: bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Como bien sabréis a los 991px o menos Bootstrap aumenta el ancho de las columnas automáticamente al 100%.

Bien pues a los 991px me parece excesivo, **lo que me gustaría es reproducir ese mismo comportamiento pero en un ancho de pantalla menor.**

¿Que propiedades aplica Bootstrap para ello? Lo digo porque inspecciono los estilos y no encuentro nada.

Comment: Tal vez puedes personalizar tu bootstrap y poner los anchos que desees: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/#container-sizes

Comment: Vaya, gracias! No sabia que se podía personalizar! Genial! Aunque después de hacerlo, descargarlo y enlazarlo correctamente a mi html todo sigue igual... He modificado los Media queries breackpoints

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiarlo con:

```
@media screen and (max-width:768px){
  .col-md-8{
     width:80%;
   }
}
```

En 768px y 80% puedes poner los puntos y porcentaje que quieras.

En .col-md-8 puedes igual poner calquier .col-...